# Apple Push Notification from Server

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification

I have followed :
[Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12). 
And it worked for me locally. 
Next, i want to send push notifications from my server?

I have uploaded `simplepush.php` and `ck.pem` to my server. When i check `http://www.myserver/simplepush.php` it gives me error:

> *Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
>   (Connection timed out) in /home/cherry/public_html/simplepush.php on
>   line 21 Failed to connect: 110 Connection timed out*

Could you please help me?

PHP Code:

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: it's not really an objective-c and xcode question, btw :)

Comment: did you manage to find that? I have the exact same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Is the PHP compiled with SSL? And is it the same version as your local version?

Or maybe the firewall of some kind blocks connection to 2195 port from your server?

Can you log in to this server (to a shell of some kind) and check if you can connect via telnet to this server and port:

```
$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
```

Comment: Trying XX.XXX.XXX.XX...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^] this is the answer i got from the terminal, when i check telnet gateway.

Comment: Okay, so it's not a blocked port. I would check if the PHP has a ssl support compiled in.

Comment: I have updated the question with the php code in my server. please check this. Anything i need to do extra?

Comment: maybe you could add a simple phpinfo(); call to your php script and look there if there's a SSL support in your php version? http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Hm... check this old blog post here and these comments: http://www.macoscoders.com/2009/05/17/iphone-apple-push-notification-service-apns/#comment-559

It might be something wrong with your certificate (maybe it's not containing the private key? Or you haven't removed the password from private key properly?)

Comment: did you manage to find that? I have the exact same problem :/